# Record Video using Media capture cordova plugin and upload to remote server issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on cordova application in which i need to capture video or choose from gallery and upload it to the remote server. I have captured the video and it path is coming but i'm not able to see the video with url and impossible to send it to server too

`

```
takeVideo() {
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1, duration: 15 }
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options)
      .then(
        (data: MediaFile[]) => {
          // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
          // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
          // let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
         // alert(data[0].fullPath)
         // this.copyFileToLocalDir(data[0].fullPath);

         alert(data[0].fullPath)
         this.dispVideos.push(data[0].fullPath)

        },
        (err: CaptureError) => {
          alert(err)
        }
      );
  }
```

`

UPLOAD METHOD
[upload method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KO9w.png)

html

```
  <div *ngIf="dispVideos?.length > 0">
        <video #myVideo preload="metadata" controls="false">
          <source [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(dispVideos[0])" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to display the video you have to insert

```
this.dispVideos.push((window as any).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(data[0].fullPath));
```

I also recently found an error on ios with the apache cordova camera plugin it provides the temporary path to the video file to come out from this error implement below changes in camera plugin.

in CDVCamera.m change THIS:

```
(CDVPluginResult*)resultForVideo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
NSString* moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] absoluteString];
return [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:filePath];
}
```

to THIS:

```
(CDVPluginResult*)resultForVideo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
NSString* moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

NSArray* spliteArray = [moviePath componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
NSString* lastString = [spliteArray lastObject];
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp"];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:lastString];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:moviePath toPath:filePath error:&error];

return [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:filePath];
}
```